# check if the css3 animation is done for example transform scale using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Hey i am working on a slider with css3 animations applied to images.
Now i wanna check if the css animations have finished then only i wanna change the slider image.
the animations are put in a class called .animations

```
    .animationStuff {
        -moz-transform: scale(1.00);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.00);
        -o-transform: scale(1.00);
        transform: scale(1.00);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.00);
    }
```

Now on button click i add the animationSuff class to image using Jquery,
how can i check if the image has scaled to normal ( i mean the animation is finished)?
thanks

Ok i've researched some more and found this answer and it works but there is one problem ,
the alert is displayed 2 times, anyways here is the code

```
  $(firstBgImage).bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function() {
    alert('hello World');
});
```

Can someone tell me why it's  displaying alter 2 times when animation ends, thanks.

Comment: [Using jQuery to Detect When CSS3 Animations and Transitions End](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-jquery-to-detect-when-css3-animations-and-transitions-end)

Comment: Do you have some tips?

Comment: `transform` is not an animation property. It does not have any duration. You're most likely confusing it with the `transition` property.

Comment: @Itay the link code dosen't work for me..

Comment: Then debug it. Don't expect someone to tell you exactly what's wrong and give you a magically fixed version. **Especialy** when you don't say what went wrong

Comment: Ok pal, please tell me what went wrong, i've updated the question. please have a look

Comment: The event is executed twice, because in some browsers you're binding it twice. For example, Chrome is likely to support both `transitioned` *and* `webkitTransitioned`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can always delete some supports such as transitioned  etc and check if problem persists.
Thanks.