# two things in one function and one of them must be waited

Tags: jquery, css

I want two things to be done in one function, I want firstly scale become 0.5 and then remove it but not working

```js
$(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
  $(this).parent().css({
    'transform': 'scale(0.5)'
  });
  $(this).parent().remove();
})
```

```css
.planarea div {
  width: 225px;
  height: 220px;
  transition: .1s;
  background: #ffff00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="planarea">
  <div>
    <a class="remove">x</a>
    <h1>asd</h1>
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
```

Comment: you can use callback functions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check if the css3 animation is done for example transform scale using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558601/check-if-the-css3-animation-is-done-for-example-transform-scale-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery's [`.one()`](https://api.jquery.com/one/) method to attach a one time event handler for the `transitionend` event. The handler will remove the element after the transition ends.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {  
  $(this).parent().one('transitionend', function() {
    $(this).remove();
  })
  .css({
    'transform': 'scale(0.5)'
  });
});
```

```css
.planarea div {
  width: 225 px;
  height: 220 px;
  transition: transform .1s;
  background: #ffff00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="planarea">
  <div>
    <a class="remove">x</a>
    <h1>asd</h1>
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```